# intel openTBB task arenas behaviour

Tags: c++, multithreading, tbb

Is it guaranteed that all tasks in the `task_arena` will be executed on the same threads set? for example I would have a rendering thread to call opengl API. Can I use something like that? Documentation isn't clear in that/

```cpp
auto rendering_arena = tbb::task_arena(1, 0);
rendering_arena.execute([](){
    while (window_available) {
        // draw something
    }
});
```

If i have two arenas, can their threads sets be intersected? Or the work isn't balanced between arenas? So, can I think of arenas as different schedulers?

I tried to write simple example. There it is:

```cpp
# include <tbb/tbb.h>

# include <iostream>
# include <sstream>
# include <thread>
#include <utility>

void task(const std::string& prefix) {
    using namespace std::chrono_literals;
    std::this_thread::sleep_for(1s);
    std::stringstream out;
    out << prefix << " on thread " << std::this_thread::get_id() << '\n';
    std::cout << out.str();
}

struct environment {
    tbb::task_arena arena;
    tbb::task_group group;
    std::string env_prefix;

    explicit environment(std::string prefix, int concurrency)
            : env_prefix(std::move(prefix)),
              arena(concurrency, 0),
              group() {}

    void run(std::size_t n) {
        arena.execute([n, this]() {
            for (std::size_t i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
                group.run([i, this]() {
                    task(env_prefix + "::" + std::to_string(i));
                });
            }
        });
    }

    void wait() {
        arena.execute([this]() {
            group.wait();
        });
    }
};

int main() {
    auto begin = tbb::tick_count::now();
    auto env1 = environment("1", 1);
    auto env2 = environment("2", 1);
    auto env3 = environment("3", 5);
    env1.run(10);
    env2.run(10);
    env3.run(10);
    std::cout << "main continue\n";
    env1.wait();
    env2.wait();
    auto end = tbb::tick_count::now();
    std::cout << "full time: " << (end - begin).seconds();
    return 0;
}
```

And that works as I expect. possible output:

```
main continue
3::3 on thread 12564
3::9 on thread 12052
1::9 on thread 2712
3::1 on thread 6200
3::2 on thread 5780
2::0 on thread 14016
3::0 on thread 2860
3::8 on thread 12052
1::8 on thread 2712
3::4 on thread 12564
3::7 on thread 2860
2::1 on thread 14016
3::6 on thread 5780
3::5 on thread 6200
2::2 on thread 14016
1::7 on thread 2712
1::6 on thread 2712
2::3 on thread 14016
1::5 on thread 2712
2::4 on thread 14016
1::4 on thread 2712
2::5 on thread 14016
1::3 on thread 2712
2::6 on thread 14016
1::2 on thread 2712
2::7 on thread 14016
1::1 on thread 2712
2::8 on thread 14016
1::0 on thread 2712
2::9 on thread 14016
full time: 10.0846
```

Answer (score 0):

I got the answer in [that](https://github.com/oneapi-src/oneTBB/issues/1012) issue. In short:

> Is it guaranteed that all tasks
> in the task_arena will be
> executed on the same threads set?

The short answer is no. Threads might migrate between arenas.

> If i have two arenas, can their threads sets be intersected?

When there is no available work in arenas threads will leave them and block(sleep) until further work submission.
Once new work will be submitted threads might join to arenas in unpredictable manner.